Combine Redis-Python pipeline with JSON
Redis provides a way to input structured JSON documents and retrieve them by content (this can, for example, power an autocomplete search experience). So I am doing this, and it is working fine:
test = "{'key': 'glooler-61245', 'val': 'sighgh'}"
r.json().set("a:glooler-61245", Path.root_path(), ast.literal_eval(test))
rs.search(Query(f"glooler"))

Redis also allows pipelines where many insertions can be streamed together and executed in one big batch, like this:
pipe = r.pipeline()
pipe.set("a", "a value")
pipe.set("b", "b value")
pipe.execute()
pipe.get("a")

However, pipe allows user to retrieve only by key, unlike the JSON one, where one can retrieve by content. How can I merge this two, so that I can push 10k structured JSONs like the first example, and then execute the pipe in one go and then be able to retrieve by value?
I tried this:
pipe.set('a:glooler-61246', "{'key': 'glooler-61246', 'val': 'loltest'}")
pipe.set('a:glooler-61247', "{'key': 'glooler-61247', 'val': 'loltest2'}")
pipe.set('a:glooler-61248', "{'key': 'glooler-61248', 'val': 'loltest3'}")
pipe.set('a:glooler-61249', "{'key': 'glooler-61249', 'val': 'loltest4'}")
pipe.execute()

However, rs.search(Query(f"glooler")) still returns only the first value I had earlier inserted.

hey hold on, in the set command, isnt it supposed to just be key and value?
can you write down the set of keys and values you want to set ?

I suspect your problem is that when pipelining you are inserting values as regular strings instead of JSONs, therefore key values are not matched during search. Try this
pipe = r.pipeline()
pipe.json().set("a:glooler-61246", Path.root_path(), ast.literal_eval("{'key': 'glooler-61246', 'val': 'loltest1'}"))
pipe.json().set("a:glooler-61247", Path.root_path(), ast.literal_eval("{'key': 'glooler-61247', 'val': 'loltest2'}"))
pipe.execute()


Yes, this fixed it! Wasn't aware about json method existing on pipe as well, could not find any documentation on it, but it makes sense. Thanks a lot!

I looked at your question again, isn't redis only supposed to store key and values? I just read the documentation again.
Can't you store them like this instead?
pipe.set('glooler-61246', 'loltest')
pipe.set('glooler-61247', 'loltest2')
pipe.set('glooler-61248', 'loltest3')
pipe.set('glooler-61249', 'loltest4')

pipe.execute()


Why do you need to store the glooler value in the key and value?

Getting error while calling pipe.execute():
redis.exceptions.DataError: Invalid input of type: 'dict'. Convert to a bytes, string, int or float first.

i read the documentation again, can you take a look at my answer now ? if its not correct, can you write down the set of keys and values you are trying to set exactly?
